# Why was my question removed?

Tags: support

I asked a questions relating to Swift and sprite-Kit : ["removeAllChildren vs. issuing 'removeFromParent' for all nodes in self.children?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240996/removeallchildren-vs-issuing-removefromparent-for-all-nodes-in-self-children) which was downvoted for some reason and then removed.

Can anyone explain why? It was a perfectly reasonable question asking why a respected tutorial had used a loop when a simple command was available to achieve the same thing and I wondered if there was some subtlety I was missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240996/removeallchildren-vs-issuing-removefromparent-for-all-nodes-in-self-children) was deleted by the system cleanup process after a month because it was downvoted and had no answers. I've undeleted it to give it another chance.

As far as the votes, we can't see who voted or possibly know why. If I had to guess, it might have to do with the fact that you don't link back to the original tutorial, so we don't have context for their code, and the fact that the authors may be the only ones who could answer that question. Again, just speculating here.

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably downvote it too. A link to the tutorial in question is simply necessary to evaluate the turotorial and to come up with a good explanation. Even with a link, the answer is still guessing, but without the link and no context, every answer is just wild speculation with no basis whatsoever. So yeah, it not a good question. It simply doesn#t include enough facts...

Comment: I've edited the question to include more of the code in question, as well as adding an answer that removeallChildren is functionally the same as child.removeFromParent for each child in the children array.

Answer (score 2):

You can always visit the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36240996/timeline) of posts to get a more detailed view on the history and order of most events. Looking at that you'll see

> `Apr 30 at 12:02  history deleted Community♦  Scheduled: RemoveDeadQuestions`

which is the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/158100) in action.

Your question got down votes because its answers could only guess why the authors of the tutorial used one method above the other. Without the context of the tutorial it is hard to tell and even with the tutorial there might still be an educational reason to use a specific code example above a more logic choice. Remember that teachers are cruel: *Sort this array in descending order but don't use the build-in Array.Sort method*. And that only gives you another set of broken sort algorithms implementations.

To give a question like yours a bit more chance you could leave out one side of the *why* but you have to provide context what your (fabricated) use-case is. Using the for loop as an example you could ask for a performance spike you see, or memory pressure or something else that can be demo-ed in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can then ask about solutions for the effect you see. Hopefully someone answers to use `removeAllChildren` and explains why that is better.